Do there exist at least two sets whose union gives the universe in a certain intersection-closed family of sets?
[Crosspost of a mathoverflow question and now answered there].
Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of $n$ finite sets. In this case, the family can be regarded as a multiset, since it is allowed to contain multiple instances of the same set. Let $U(\mathcal{F})$ be the universe, i.e. the union of all sets in $\mathcal{F}$.
We require that:

$\mathcal{F}$ is intersection-closed ($\mathcal{F}$ must contain at least one instance of $A \cap B$ for any $A,B \in \mathcal{F}$);
every element in $U(\mathcal{F})$ belongs to at least $\lceil (n-1)/2 \rceil$ sets of $\mathcal{F}$ (every set is counted with its multiplicity).

Is it possible to prove that, for any possible choice of $\mathcal{F}$, there exist $A, B \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $A \cup B = U(\mathcal{F})$?
Maybe a sketch of a possible approach could be starting from the power set $\mathcal{P}(U(\mathcal{F}))$, then try to remove an intersection irreducible set to obtain another intersection-closed family modifying set multiplicites as needed by requirement $2$, and show that we cannot do that without removing all intersection irreducible sets of the same size. Alternatively, start from an intersection-closed family without any $A,B$ such that $A \cup B = U(\mathcal{F})$, then show that if we add sets still without such $A, B$, then condition $2$ keeps being unsatisfied.

Three disjoint singletons with $U = {1,2,3}$ would satisfy your requirements and they would be a counter-example. What do you mean $A\cap B \in \mathcal{F}$? Does it include the empty set or not?

@TheAlertGerbil yes ${1} \cap {2} = \emptyset$ and then it must be $\emptyset \in \mathcal{F}$ so $\lceil (n-1)/2 \rceil$ becomes $2$ and the counter-example is not valid anymore.
